# Saving string as blob object in csv using java

Tags: java, string, csv, blob, export-to-csv

I want my app to save `Strings` as `Blob` object in a `csv` file, blob object will be another colomn in the `csv` file. 
for example
record1, record2, record3 stored as a `blob` object.

Comment: Is there a specific question in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) :

> A comma-separated values (CSV) file stores tabular data (numbers and text) in plain text.

So, you can't store anything else than text in a csv